# Google Apps Script : how to resize an image present on Google Drive?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-apps

I want to resize some images present on Google Drive thanks to a Google script. How can I do that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no native method to do this using Apps Script.

But luckily, you can do this fairly easily thanks to this [external library](https://github.com/tanaikech/ImgApp). As explained in the provided link, once you import it, you can access its methods with `ImgApp`.

One of those methods, [doResize()](https://github.com/tanaikech/ImgApp#doresize), is what you're looking for. But please be aware of the [limitations](https://github.com/tanaikech/ImgApp#doresize_limitations) associated with this method.

I hope this is of any help.